# Why is it that SQL statements, created with VB.Net SQLClient, don't show up in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am programming in VB.Net, and I am wondering if there is an internal mechanism for generating a stored procedure purely as a coded process.  I have text strings that represent stored procedures, and I would like to be able to control these strings and have me dictate what constitutes a stored procedure, hopefully as an internal process, not having to rely on Executing an SSMS connection.

Since publishing this originally, I have seen and responded to suggestions, and this is what I have so far:

```
Dim UseServer As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strConnection)
UseServer.Open()
    
Dim UseCommand As SqlClient.SqlCommand = UseServer.CreateCommand
UseCommand.CommandText = "Create Procedure dbo.ABC As BEGIN Select 'Dog' End"
UseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I run this, it completes without a hitch, although here's the rub: When I refresh my list of existing stored procedures, I do not see "ABC" listed, and I am free to create an ABC using SSMS, which it will without complaint.  Yet, when I run the code above twice, first creating the stored procedure, and the second time attempting to overwrite the same procedure, I get an error.

Something is not computing here.  The connection is verifiably opening in the correct database, yet the SQL Client seems to be maintaining a stored procedure separate from what SSMS is storing.  I would love for someone to explain this to me.  Could it be that the stored procedure that the SQLClient stores is hidden or stored elsewhere.  I would like some clarity about what I'm seeing.  Thank you.

Comment: As a hobby project it could be fun

Comment: First, you should use `SqlClient` instead of `ADODB` in .NET code (e.g. `UseConn.ExecuteNonQuery("Alter Procedure ABC AS Begin Select 'Dog' End"))`. You can execute any DDL from app code without needing to do so from SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) are objects designed for programmatic management of MicrosoftSQL Server. You can use SMO to build customized SQL Server management applications. Although SQL Server Management Studio is a powerful and extensive application for managing SQL Server, there might be times when you would be better served by an SMO application.

[microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/overview-smo?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You Need to create Store Procedure and Execute like :

```
                    var ConnectionString = "Put Your Connection String Here";
                    
                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
                            
                            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("EXEC SP_NAME");
                            
                            server.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                             Console.WriteLine(" Error : " + ex.Message);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: OK: I'm making some progress here, but there is still a mystery.  This is my query so far: